# Find records that were active in a certain date range using linq c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I need to list the records that were Active in a certain point in a period of time:

The concept of Active here is the range between DateActivation and DateDeactivation.

Model:

```
public class DME
{
    public DateTime DateActivation { get; set; }               // Is always set
    public Nullable<DateTime> DateDeactivation { get; set; }   // Set or Null
}
```

Action:

```
public ActionResult ActiveRecordsInTimeFrame(string DateStart, string DateFinish)
{
    IList<int> dmeIds = db.DMEs
                        .AsEnumerable()
                        .Where(d => d.DateActivation >= Convert.ToDateTime(DateStart))
                        .Where(d => d.DateActivation <= Convert.ToDateTime(DateFinish))
                        .Where(d => d.DateDeactivation == null || d.DateDeactivation <= Convert.ToDateTime(DateFinish))
                        .Select(d => d.Id).ToList();

}
```

I am not getting this to work properly, because I can't get the records when the DateActivation < DateStart and DateDeactivation is null for example, or when DateActivation > 
DateStart and DateDeactivation > DateFinish

I think there are 5 cases where the records were active in time:

```
 DateActivation | DateStart | DateDeactivation  | DateFinish

 DateStart | DateActivation | DateDeactivation  | DateFinish

 DateStart | DateActivation | DateFinish | DateDeactivation

 DateActivation | DateStart | DateFinish | DateDeactivation = NULL

 DateStart | DateActivation | DateFinish | DateDeactivation = NULL
```

Any help please?

Thanks.

Comment: `I am not getting the correct records in some situations.` ??

Comment: This is the all point of your query..just the dates in the range and not in all situations.

Comment: Hi, thanks. Basically it's not working at all:)

Comment: @YairNevet Hi thanks. I only want the active ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should be the condition you're looking for:

```
(d.DateActivation == null || dtStart < d.DateDeactivation) && dtEnd > d.DateActivation
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
public class DME
{
    public DateTime DateActivation { get; set; }               // Is always set
    public DateTime? DateDeactivation { get; set; }   // Set or Null
}

public ActionResult ActiveRecordsInTimeFrame(string DateStart, string DateFinish)
{
    var model = GetActiveRecordsBetweenDates(
                    Convert.ToDateTime(DateStart), 
                    Convert.ToDateTime(DateFinish)).ToList();

    ...
}

...

private IQueryble<IEnumerable<int>> 
        GetActiveRecordsBetweenDates(DateTime dtStart, DateTime? dtEnd) 
{
    if(dtEnd.HasValue)
    {
        // both dates provided
        return from db in db.DMEs
               where d.DateActivation >= dtStart &&
                     d.DateActivation <= dtEnd
               select db.Id;
    }

    // no end date
    return from db in db.DMEs
           where d.DateActivation >= dtStart
           select db.Id;
}
```

---

UPDATED from a comment: `I only want the active ones.`

and assuming that if `DateDeactivation` has a date, it's because it's already deactivated

```
private IQueryble<IEnumerable<int>> 
        GetActiveRecordsBetweenDates(DateTime dtStart, DateTime? dtEnd) 
{
    if(dtEnd.HasValue)
    {
        // both dates provided
        return from db in db.DMEs
               where d.DateActivation >= dtStart &&
                     d.DateActivation <= dtEnd && 
                     d.DateDeactivation == null
               select db.Id;
    }

    // no end date
    return from db in db.DMEs
           where d.DateActivation >= dtStart && 
                 d.DateDeactivation == null
           select db.Id;
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks, but how you take care of the case where (DateActivation > dtStart and DateActivation < dtEnd) and ( DateDeactivation > dtEnd or NULL) ?

Comment: You can do it in just one query, like this: `from db in db.DMEs where d.DateActivation >= dtStart && (!dtEnd.HasValue || d.DateActivation <= dtEnd) select db.Id;`

Comment: @thepirat000 hi thanks, but how you take care of the case (DateActivation < dtStart) and (DateDeactivation < dtEnd and DateDeactivation > dtStart)?

Comment: @thepirat000 I can, but I don't thing Patrick get's it... - @Patrick you mention that **is between the given dates**, so it will never be `DateActivation < dtStart` and when `dtEnd` is `null` it does not even use that date... it will be the same as `from PAST_DATE to TODAY`

Comment: @Patrick I think the record is not active if *DateActivation < dtStart*, right?

Comment: @thepirat000 the record can be active yes, check my definition of active in my question, I also completed the question with "I need to list the records that were Active in a certain point in a period of time"

Comment: @Patrick updated assuming that `DateDeactivation` is null if record is active.

Comment: @balexandre you are missing the case where DateActivation < DateStart and DateDeactivation  < DateFinish for example

Comment: I'm not going **to do your work** Patrick, if I'm missing, try yourself, do something! We here only to help you get into the right path, not do ones work!

Comment: @balexandre Sorry to bother you.